# Toggle the content of a div and change the height of another div in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to toggle the height and to display two different `divs` on the same `onclick` event with jquery. I feel like I may be missing something small or a rule in jquery that I don't know. On the first click everything displays and changes height like planned, but the second does not minimize the content.

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.readmore').on('click', function(event) {        
        if (jQuery("#content").height() == 500) {
            jQuery("#content").animate(
                {height: "750px"});
            jQuery('#hidden').toggle('show');
       } 
        else {
            $("#content").animate({height: "500px"});
            jQuery('#hidden').toggle('hide');
       }
    });
});
```

The div starts off as `500px` tall and want to toggle them between that and `750px` while switching between  displaying the content in `#hidden`.

here is my **HTML**

```
<div id="content">
<p></p>
<div id="hidden" style="font-size:18px">
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content3">
<p><a class="readmore" href="javascript://">Read More </a></div>
```

Comment: Please post your html as well

Comment: Thank you! Just added it in

Comment: well, your using `jQuery` on all lines except the line after `else`. You sure the $ is not the issue?

Comment: Seems perfectly functional to me: https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/5f4h19c1/1/ Although `jQuery('#hidden').toggle('show');` and  `jQuery('#hidden').toggle('hide');` rely on you having `.show` and `.hide` **classes**. You could just use `jQuery('#hidden').show()` or `jQuery('#hidden').hide()`

Comment: Update using simple `show()` and `hide()` : https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/5f4h19c1/2/

Comment: Hey Scott the fixed it! just switched to jquery('#hidden').show() and the same for hide. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merely use the built in `show()` and `hide()` functions with jQuery.

As you have it, this:

```
jQuery('#hidden').toggle('show');
```

and this

```
jQuery('#hidden').toggle('hide');
```

are toggling the **classes** `.show` and `.hide`. Therefore if your classes differ from the default styling, they may be altering the functionality you are expecting. You need the `.hide` class to hide things initially, but after that it's not necessary to toggle that class.

The jQuery also assume the initial div is *always* 500px tall. So, if the `#content` div is less than 500px tall, it takes 2 clicks to minimize it again. You can tweak the function to account for instances where the div is less than 500px tall and it should all still work as expected.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.readmore').on('click', function(event) {        
        if (jQuery("#content").height() <= 500) {
            jQuery("#content").animate(
                {height: "750px"});
            jQuery('#hidden').show();
       } 
        else {
            $("#content").animate({height: "500px"});
            jQuery('#hidden').hide();
       }
    });
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
div { padding: 20px; }
#content { background: #aaa;}
#hidden { background: #eee;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<p>displayed text</p>
<div id="hidden" class="hide" style="font-size:18px">
<p>hidden text</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content3">
<p><a class="readmore" href="javascript://">Read More </a></div>
```

This will expand the height to 750px regardless of the initial height... then minimize to 500px on the second click.

Answer (score 0):

> It will be very handy if you use custom **css** classes to change style of **DOM** elements and animating elements with **css** transitions
>   rather than writing too much code of **jQuery**.

Here is the **snippet**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.readmore').on('click', function(event) {        
        jQuery("#content").toggleClass("expand");
    });
});
```

```css
#content{
   height:100px;
   background-color:#f0f0f0;
   border:1px solid #E5EAF2;
   -webkit-transition:height 0.6s linear;
   transition:height 0.6s linear;
}

.expand{
   height: 750px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<p></p>
<div id="hidden" style="font-size:18px">
<p>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content3">
<p><a class="readmore" href="javascript://">Read More </a></div>
```

In the above **snippet** i have created a css class `expand` and just toggling that class with jquery, hence the height as well.
And for transitions i have used `css transitions` to `#content`.

Hope it helps.